# "non-conformable arrays" error when subtracting or dividing matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 5x3 matrix called `matrixoutput`:

```
matrixoutput <- structure(c(755.012517738809, 713.680227809506, 796.559832334474, 
720.586278415567, 813.656728335122, 747.228849872966, 716.763851131365, 
790.005405393554, 719.099072835892, 794.80633176412, 747.924859415065, 
714.405749195011, 792.123774606548, 719.75129988389, 793.458302292789
), .Dim = c(5L, 3L))
```

I have a 5x1 matrix called `matrixactual`:

```
matrixactual <- structure(c(743.2, 710.37, 787.77, 721.41, 808), .Dim = c(5L, 
1L))
```

I am trying to run a "MAPE" calculation for each column in `matrixoutput` as such:

```
MAPE <- mean(abs((matrixactual-matrixoutput)/matrixactual) * 100)
```

However this returns the error:

> Error in matrixactual - matrixoutput : non-conformable arrays

Any idea of a workaround?  I imagine there is a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrixactual <- c(matrixactual)  ## I mean `base::c`
colMeans(abs((matrixactual - matrixoutput) / matrixactual) * 100)
```

["Recycling rule"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) works behind that `"-"` and `"/"`.

---

Sometimes we may encounter even more obscured situation:

```
A <- matrix(1:15, 5, 3)
b <- array(1:5, dim = 5)
b
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

`b` looks like a vector, but it is actually not. It is a 1D array with "dim" attribute. `"-"` would complain non-conformable dimension.

```
A - b
#Error in A - b : non-conformable arrays
```

Use `A - c(b)` to actually use "recycling rule".

Also, `"%*%"` would fail.

```
A %*% b
#Error in A %*% b : non-conformable arguments
```

The solution is `A %*% c(b)`.

1D array is returned by `table` function when it is used on a single input. So my elaboration here just wants to say: perhaps a robust piece of code should check dimension always.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
colMeans(abs(sweep(matrixoutput, 1, matrixactual)) / rep(matrixactual,3))
```

The key here is to keep track of the dimension. You can easily subtract matrixes of the same dimension from each other, but when the dimensions differ, it gets tricky. In your case, R gave you an error message when you tried to subtract a vector from a matrix.

Here, `sweep(a, 1, b)` removes each value in `b` from the corresponding row in `a`. Then you need to divide with an object whose dimension is aligned with `matrixoutput`, which is the case if you repeat `matrixactual` three times.

An alternative would be

```
colMeans((matrixoutput - rep(matrixactual, 3)) / rep(matrixactual,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `matrixactual-matrixoutput`. You are subtracting a 5x3 matrix from a 5x1 matrix. Subtraction in this way is a one to one operation and requires objects of the same dimension. You should use `sweep` and `colMeans` to get the correct number of dimensions:

```
MAPE <- colMeans(abs(sweep(matrixoutput,1,matrixactual)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This:
MAPE<- colMeans(abs(-matrixoutput + matrixactual[,1]))
gives: `[1] 6.078606 5.632540 5.862956`

Which is identical to the output of:
MAPE <- colMeans(abs(sweep(matrixoutput,1,matrixactual)))

This is, I think, more straightforward to de non-R programmer.
However, I do not understand why the [,1] is necessary.